# Two clients do not communicate on python with ssl

Tags: ssl, server, client, chat

El servidor tiene problemas para funcionar, he sacado el código de openai.com, pero parece que sus respuestas estan sacadas del código de personas que han posteado dudas y problemas en lugar de ejemplos funcionales.

El servidor.

```
import socketserver
import ssl

class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port, context):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.context = context
        self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        self.context.load_cert_chain(certfile='./cer.pem', keyfile='./clave.key')
        self.server = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), ServerHandler, context)
        self.server.clients = []

    def start(self):
        self.server.serve_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.server.server_close()
        
    def send_message_to_all_clients(self, message):
        for client in self.server.clients:
            client.sendall(message)

class ServerHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        self.context = context
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server)
        
    def handle(self):
        self.server.clients.append(self.request)
        self.request = self.context.wrap_socket(self.request, server_side=True)
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            self.send_message_to_all_clients(data)

    def send_message_to_all_clients(self, message, context):
        for client in self.server.clients:
            client = context.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True)
            client.sendall(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8080
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile='./cer.pem', keyfile='./clave.key')
    server = Server(host, port, context)
    server.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python


from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

from cifrar import CIFRAR
from descifrar import DESCIFRAR
from comprobar import *
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, pyqtSignal


class Ventana(QMainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Icono
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('v.png'))

        #Variables de estado
        self.conectado=False

        #Fuente tipo negrita
        fetiqueta=QFont()
        fetiqueta.setBold(True)

        #Avatar
        self.archivoAvatar = "avatar.png"
        self.avatar = QLabel(self)
        self.avatar.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.archivoAvatar).scaled(120, 120, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.avatar.move(720,130)
        self.avatar.resize(120,120)
        self.avatar.show()

        #Texto de entrada
        self.lineEntry = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.lineEntry.move(10,10)
        self.lineEntry.resize(700,200)
        self.lineEntry.setReadOnly(True)
        
        #Texto a enviar
        self.linaEnvio = QLineEdit(self)
        self.linaEnvio.move(10,500)
        self.linaEnvio.resize(700,40)
        self.linaEnvio.setReadOnly(False)
        
        #Texto estado y avisos
        self.linestado = QLineEdit(self)
        self.linestado.move(10,210)
        self.linestado.resize(700,40)
        self.linestado.setReadOnly(True)
        
        #Etiqueta bajo boton conectar -> IP
        self.etiquetaIPS = QLabel(self)
        self.etiquetaIPS.move(720,60)
        self.etiquetaIPS.setText("IP:192.168.1.100  ")
        self.etiquetaIPS.setStyleSheet("font-weight: 300")

        #Etiqueta bajo boton conectar -> Puerto
        self.etiquetaPS = QLabel(self)
        self.etiquetaPS.move(720,80)
        self.etiquetaPS.setText("Puerto: 8080 ")
        self.etiquetaPS.setStyleSheet("font-weight: 300")
        
        #Etiqueta bajo boton conectar -> Certificados
        self.etiquetaCer = QLabel(self)
        self.etiquetaCer.move(720,100)
        self.etiquetaCer.setText("Puerto: 8080 ")
        self.etiquetaCer.setStyleSheet("font-weight: 300")

        #Boton conectar
        self.boton1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.boton1.move(720,10)
        self.boton1.resize(130,40)
        self.boton1.setText("Conectar")
        self.boton1.setFont(fetiqueta)
        self.boton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        #Boton cerrar
        self.boton2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.boton2.move(720,550)
        self.boton2.resize(130,40)
        self.boton2.setFont(fetiqueta)
        self.boton2.setText("Cerrar")
        
        #Boton Enviar
        self.boton3 = QPushButton(self)
        self.boton3.move(10,550)
        self.boton3.resize(700,40)
        self.boton3.setText("Enviar")
        self.boton3.setFont(fetiqueta)

        #Señales
        self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.conectar)
        self.boton2.clicked.connect(self.cerrar)
        self.boton3.clicked.connect(self.enviar)
        
        # self.avatar.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarAvatar)
        
        #Ventana principal
        self.setGeometry(50,50,860,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Chat")
        self.show()

    #Funciones
    def alinicio(self):
        #Comprobamos estado de conexión, coloreamos boton de conexión y desactivamos boton y linea de envio
        self.conecado = True
        if self.conectado == False:
            self.linestado.setText("Pulsa en el botón Desconectado para empezar.")
            self.linaEnvio.setEnabled(False)
            self.boton3.setEnabled(False)
            self.boton1.setText("Desconectado")
            self.boton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        else:
            self.linestado.setText("Conexión establecida!")
            self.linaEnvio.setEnabled(True)
            self.boton3.setEnabled(True)
            self.conectado == True
            self.boton1.setText("Conectado")
            self.boton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
            
        #Comprobamos existencia de certificados
        if os.path.isfile('./public0.pem') and os.path.isfile('./privad0.pem'):
            self.etiquetaCer.setText("Certificados OK")
        elif not os.path.isfile('./public0.pem') and not os.path.isfile('./privad0.pem'):
            self.etiquetaCer.setText("¿Certificados?")
            self.linestado.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
            self.linestado.setText("Faltan los certificados de cifrado!")

    def seleccionarAvatar(self):
            self.avatar = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Selecciona una imagen',".","Imagenes (*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)")
            if self.avatar:
                self.image = QImage(self.avatar)
                if self.image.isNull():
                    popup = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Critical, "Image load error", "Could not load image file!", QMessageBox.Ok, self)
                    popup.show()
                else:
                    cursor = self.text.textCursor()
                    cursor.insertImage(self.image, self.avatar) 

    def conectar(self):
        self.conectado=True
        self.alinicio()

    def enviar(self, texto):
        texto = self.linaEnvio.text()
        tes = b''
        resultado = tes + texto.encode('utf-8')

        if self.linaEnvio.text():
            key = RSA.import_key(open('public0.pem').read())
            cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
            textoCifrado = cipher.encrypt(resultado)
            self.lineEntry.appendPlainText(str(textoCifrado))
        else:
            self.linestado.setText("Escribe algo en el campo de texto encima del botón enviar...")

    def cerrar(self):
        self.seleccionarAvatar()
       # sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ventana()
    ex.alinicio()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# des= DESCIFRAR(cif)
# print(des)



# Aquí esta una solución.

# key = RSA.import_key(open('privad0.pem').read())
# cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
# textoDesCifrado = cipher.decrypt(mensaje)
# return textoDesCifrado.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Abajo del todo hay una solución que encontre y funciona.